# How to upgrade/reinstall package(scikit-learn) using Anaconda

Tags: python, package, upgrade, scikit-learn

I have been using Anaconda with sklearn 0.13.1 originally installed (IIRC) on win7, py2 x32:

```
In [2]: sklearn
Out[2]: <module 'sklearn' from 'D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sklearn\__init__.pyc'>
```

Now I want to upgrade sklearn to 0.14.1. I tried:

1. install sklearn 0.14 using executable installer downloaded from [HERE](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn). But it still shows the same info as above when `import sklearn`.
2. I searched on my disk, now I indeed have 2 folders containing different versions:

> ```
> D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg
> D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7.egg-info
> ```

Then I try to uninstall the older version, but all the following ways failed:

- `control pannel -> uninstall programs`, I can see **only** Python 2.7
  scikit-learn-0.14.1 there to uninstall. That should be an uninstaller put
  on my system when installing sklearn-0.14.1 with that executable just
  now.
- `pip uninstall sklearn` outputs:

  > Cannot uninstall requirement sklearn, not installed Storing complete
  >   log in C:\Users\zhangxaochen\pip\pip.log
- try editing `D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth`, replace
  this line:

  > ./scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-win32.egg

  with

  > ./scikit_learn-0.14.1-py2.7.egg-info

Could someone tell me how can I upgrade successfully? I don't want to reinstall my python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, stupid error operation...

I did copy&past to make a backup of the original `easy-install.pth` with name `easy-install - 副本.pth`, but forgot to rename the extention to `.bak` . Thus python still look up this backup file and my edit of `easy-install.pth` took no effect ;\